# assembly -- Why subtract `rsp` rather than push when dealing with local variables?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, micro-optimization

When dealing with local variables, the normal way is after pushing `rbp` and moving `rsp`'s value to `rbp`, we subtract `rsp` to reserve space in the head of function, and accessing local variables via `rbp`. I wonder why not just push one once meeting a local variable, and we can still access local variables via `rbp`.

Comment: It's faster to subtract once than pushing multiple times.

Comment: clang *does* do a dummy push/pop when it needs to move RSP by exactly 8 bytes.